# If $a\neq 2$ and $a^3+a^2-a-10 = 0$, then evaluate $a+\frac{5}{a}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring, cubics

> If $a\neq 2$ and $a^{3}+a^{2}-a-10 = 0$, then what is the value of $a+\dfrac{5}{a}$?

I have plugged equation on WolframAlpha and get the complex values of $a$ but you supposed to do this problem using factoring and very elementary algebra. I tried divide both sides of equation to get $a+\frac{5}{a}$, but the coefficients are given in a way that is hard to factor.

Comment: Why is the problem stupid?

Comment: it is a pointless factoring problem on 10th grade test and ı yet can't do it :(

Comment: Note that it factors as $(a-2)(a^2+3a+5)=0$.

Comment: @BilalErgüç There are not stupid questions

Answer (score 3):

Just factor the given equation to get $(a-2)(a^2+3a+5)=0$. Since $a\neq2$, we must have $a^2+3a+5=0$. Now divide both sides by $a$ to get $$a+5/a=-3$$

Comment: thanks, ı feel kinda stupid now studying competition math but not being able to see such a thing

Comment: Since $a\ne 2,$ you mean?

Comment: Yes! Sorry I did a typo. Fixed it now.